# CCK Demodulation

Tags: matlab, network-programming, wireless

I am implementing the Demodulator for CCK modulation scheme used in IEEE 802.11b Standard.

But I am not sure, how to implement it. I read about Walsh Transform and Fast Walsh Transform.

How does Walsh Transform help in the demodulation/despreading. Also, any useful pointers in this direction would be helpful.

BTW, I am implementing the CCK demodulator in matlab

Comment: Well, I just developed the code for modulation and demodulation in Matlab using the CCK  Encoding table. Just in case, if someone is interested, here is the code for the CCK encoding table: http://matlab.my/hj870O